# Get CPU for process in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to get the value that is shown in task manager for any process in the CPU column in powershell.

I tried using

```
Get-Process ProcessName | Select-Object -Property CPU
```

but it only returns the time spent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684/name-of-the-process-with-highest-cpu-usage/51820#51820

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`Get-Counter`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx) command which pulls the data from the system's performance monitor. For your example, it would look like this:

```
# ~> Get-Counter "\Process(ProcessName*)\% Processor Time" | select -expand countersamples
```

An example, using chrome:

```
# ~> Get-Counter "\Process(chrome*)\% Processor Time" | select -expand countersamples 

Path                                            InstanceName      CookedValue
----                                            ------------      -----------
\\machinename\process(chrome#7)\% processor time chrome                      0
\\machinename\process(chrome#6)\% processor time chrome                      0
\\machinename\process(chrome#5)\% processor time chrome                      0
\\machinename\process(chrome#4)\% processor time chrome                      0
\\machinename\process(chrome#3)\% processor time chrome                      0
\\machinename\process(chrome#2)\% processor time chrome                      0
\\machinename\process(chrome#1)\% processor time chrome                      0
\\machinename\process(chrome)\% processor time   chrome       3.10141153081511
```

Comment: Thanks for the post but I got it working by the code :

`get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process| Select-Object -Property Name, PercentProcessorTime`

Comment: How do I get it to also show the process ID? I find it useless without the ID because I have multiple processes running that are the same name and need to know which one is stuck using the CPU so I don’t kill the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some copy-pastable examples of filtering processes with `Get-Counter` and `Get-WmiObject`.

For example, to get the top 10 processes by CPU usage:

```
powershell "(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples | Sort cookedvalue -Desc| Select -First 10 instancename, cookedvalue"
```

Or, with cleaner formatting:

```
powershell "(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples | Sort cookedvalue -Desc | Select -First 10 instancename, @{Name='CPU %';Expr={[Math]::Round($_.CookedValue)}}"
```

```
powershell "gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Sort PercentProcessorTime -desc | Select -first 7 Name, PercentProcessorTime, IOReadBytesPersec, IOWriteBytesPersec, WorkingSet | ft -autoformat"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way I would go on achieving this is

```
get-process processName | where-object {$_.cpu -gt desirevalue}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the command that OP used originally and found that it didn't work for them. Could you explain what is different in your answer? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].